# An Area51 proposal

Tags: discussion

I want to bring the following Area51 proposal to your attention:

> [Computational  Science proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science?referrer=CKiV7bfahFWu25kobpt0GA2)

It is for [Computation **al** Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science) (not Computer Science).

It seems like a solid proposal and can be useful for scientists outside computer science using computers, and I think we should support it. (It can also be interesting for us).

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “we should support it,” but note that there is a discussion about the scope of this proposal and other related ones: [Shall we unite computational science proposals?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/320/shall-we-unite-computational-science-proposals).  I have nothing for or against these proposals.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I shouldn't have used "should" and "we". :) What I meant is that take a look at the proposal and if you like it follow it and upvote proposed on-topic/off-topic questions and ...

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.